# WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "x264enc"

Tags: macos, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I have been trying to get this running for the past couple of days now. I have a gstreamer command that requires x264enc. I am running a **Mac** I cannot seem to get x264 development libraries installed. I have installed `gst-plugins-bad` but that does not help. I read in forums I need to install x264 libraries first before installing `gst-plugins-bad`

I also tried VideoLAN's http://www.videolan.org/developers/x264.html That did not help either. I don't know what I'm missing. If it was Linux I could install the x264-devel packages. But I can't seem to find an alternative to that on Mac El Capitan.

The error I get is:

> WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "x264enc"

Please help.

Answer (score 7):

Try:
brew install gst-plugins-ugly --with-x264

Comment: Homebrew has removed all additional options (grr!) so `--with-x264` no longer works. Does anyone know how to get 264 now? Is it just part of `gst-plugins-ugly` now?

Comment: @JasonAxelson yes it should work without the --with-x264

Answer (score 3):

`x264enc` is in `gst-plugins-ugly`, have you installed that? [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) is a popular package manager for macOS, installing gstreamer and x264 using that may be helpful also.

Answer (score 1):

Build all module of GStreamer in follows sequence:

```
(1) Gstreamer-1.0
(2) gst-libav-1.8.3
(3) gst-plugins-base-1.8.3
(4) gst-plugins-good-1.8.3
(5) gst-plugins-bad-1.8.3
(6) gst-plugins-ugly-1.8.3
```

Set below path :

```
export PATH=$PATH:<install_dir_path>/bin 
                         export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<install_dir_path>/lib
                         export GST_PLUGIN_PATH=<install_dir_path>/lib/gstreamer-1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

## Shot answer

For me, it started working after I installed `ugly` package. I use Ubuntu, my install command is:

```bash
sudo apt install -y gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly
```

## Similar case with solution

I had the similar issue with Ubuntu 22.04. But my first missing package was `qtdemux`. Originally I followed @brendan-shanks's answer (it worked) and on another machine tried @pooja's answer.

My command looks like this:

```bash
gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location="/home/ubuntu/countdown_10_min.mp4" ! qtdemux ! video/x-h264 ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=8004
```

Following @pooja's solution I'v run several commands before it started working:

```bash
sudo apt install -y gstreamer1.0-plugins-base
sudo apt install -y gstreamer1.0-libav
sudo apt install -y gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly
sudo apt install -y gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad
```

I don't know if `qtdemux` is in `plugins-bad` but only after that I was able to run my stream.

So, in similar case I would check packages @pooja have mentioned. For Ubuntu they are:

```bash
sudo apt install -y gstreamer1.0-tools
sudo apt install -y gstreamer1.0-libav
sudo apt install -y gstreamer1.0-plugins-base
sudo apt install -y gstreamer1.0-plugins-good
sudo apt install -y gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad
sudo apt install -y gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly
```

Answer (score -1):

```
# building gst-plugins-ugly
export version=1.14.5
echo "building gst-plugins-ugly-$version"
cd $PROJECT_DIR/gst-plugins-ugly-$version
./autogen.sh
./configure --with-x264-libraries=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libx264.so
make -j8
sudo make install
```

Comment: Avoid code only answer and provide an explanation.