# No such element or plugin 'v4l2h264enc'

Tags: gstreamer, v4l2

I'm trying to use GStreamer from docker container, built using [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/selkies-vdi/blob/cgc-docs/images/gst-base/Dockerfile) Dockerfile.

The installation worked ok and I'm able to run GStreamer. However, I'm not able to use the element `v4l2h264enc` with the error that does not exist. When I run gst-inspect I get:

```
root@95e1ff54cca5:~# gst-inspect-1.0 v4l2h264enc
No such element or plugin 'v4l2h264enc'
```

But `v4l2src` works fine:

```
root@95e1ff54cca5:~# gst-inspect-1.0 v4l2src
Factory Details:
  Rank                     primary (256)
  Long-name                Video (video4linux2) Source
  Klass                    Source/Video
  Description              Reads frames from a Video4Linux2 device
  Author                   Edgard Lima <edgard.lima@gmail.com>, Stefan Kost <ensonic@users.sf.net>

Plugin Details:
  Name                     video4linux2
  Description              elements for Video 4 Linux
  Filename                 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstvideo4linux2.so
  Version                  1.18.0
  License                  LGPL
  Source module            gst-plugins-good
  Source release date      2020-09-08
  Binary package           GStreamer Good Plug-ins source release
  Origin URL               Unknown package origin
```

I have checked in the `build` folder of `gst-plugins-good` and I think that `v4l2h265enc` library was compiled (there's a file named `gstv4l2h265enc.c.o`). I tried to add the folder where the file is to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `GST_PLUGIN_PATH` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with on a raspberrypi 4  with gstreamer and solved it by enabling the kernel side support (often referenced as "v4l2m2m").

You can check it is activated because you get new /dev/video character device files in addition to /dev/video0. (for me it's 3 new files /dev/video[10,11,12]).

Check that the kernel module is loaded or load it with:

```
modprobe bcm2835-codec
```

Then `gst-inspect-1.0 video4linux2` should show you the elements you are looking for, such as v4l2h264dec, v4l2h264enc, v4l2vp8dec, .... (sometimes gst-inspect-1.0 does not really retry but relies on a cache which might not reflect recent changes: removing the cache can be helpful. In my install I do `rm ~/.cache/gstreamer-1.0/registry.armv8-a.bin`)

Comment: Ok, thanks! I'll try it. It turns out that I was not starting correctly the docker image. I was missing the parameters `--privileged --device=/dev/video0:/dev/video*`. When linking the devices correctly it already shows `v4l2h264enc`. However, another error shows up related to missing codecs. Perhaps it's related to your answer.

Comment: You're welcome. On my side, the element v4l2h264enc now exists, but unfortunately doesn't work: seems to be a problem on the kernel side...

Comment: I just got the v4l2h264enc working on both a zero and a 64bits 4. Both with kernel 5.10.14+ and gstreamer 1.18.1. The key is to use a caps filter : gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! v4l2h264enc ! 'video/x-h264,level=(s
tring)3' ! filesink location=foo.h264

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error while running `gstreamer` on Ubuntu within my laptop. As I understand, `v4l2h264enc` is for raspberrypi and there were no `v4l2h264enc` on my laptop. So my solution was - to find analog. `x264enc` solved my issue.

Here's my original command (for running within raspberrypi):

```bash
gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! image/jpeg , width=640, height=480 , framerate=15/1 ! jpegdec ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw , colorimetry=bt601 ! v4l2h264enc extra-controls="encode,video_bitrate=368640,video_bitrate_mode=1,h264_level=10,h264_profile=0;" ! 'video/x-h264,profile=high,level=(string)3.2' ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=8004 audiotestsrc wave=4 ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! audio/x-raw,channels=1,rate=16000 ! opusenc bitrate=20000 ! rtpopuspay pt=97 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=8005
```

And here's command for laptop:

```bash
gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! image/jpeg , width=640, height=480 , framerate=15/1 ! jpegdec ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw , colorimetry=bt601 ! x264enc bitrate=368640 tune=zerolatency ! 'video/x-h264,profile=high,level=(string)3.2' ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=8004 audiotestsrc wave=4 ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! audio/x-raw,channels=1,rate=16000 ! opusenc bitrate=20000 ! rtpopuspay pt=97 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=8005
```

---

So, the difference is just within these parts:

```
v4l2h264enc extra-controls="encode,video_bitrate=368640,video_bitrate_mode=1,h264_level=10,h264_profile=0;"
```

turned into

```bash
x264enc bitrate=368640 tune=zerolatency
```

---

I believe this issue differs from author's question but may be helpful to someone.

---

## Another possible solution

is to try installing all necessary packages. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74290514/7744106) I described what I was issuing with. I managed to get `x264enc` work after installing `ugly` package:

```bash
sudo apt install -y gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly
```

So, I believe the soultion is to try install all this packages one after another:

```bash
sudo apt install -y gstreamer1.0-tools
sudo apt install -y gstreamer1.0-libav
sudo apt install -y gstreamer1.0-plugins-base
sudo apt install -y gstreamer1.0-plugins-good
sudo apt install -y gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad
sudo apt install -y gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly
```

Comment: Note that `x264enc` is a **software encoder** using `libx264` and will be very CPU intensive - it does not attempt to use your GPU hardware at all.